# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'parameter_store_extension'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I created two lambda layers. Both from zip files, in which the first one includes python dependencies

```
# resumebuilder_utils.zip
.
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
│   └── utils.cpython-310.pyc
├── python
│   └── lib
│       └── python3.10
│           └── site-packages
├── requirements.txt
└── utils.py
```

My lambda function can use the functions inside `utils.py` like this

```
from utils import hash_password, normalize_value_object
```

As for the second layer, this one does not need any dependencies since it only consists of one file

```
# parameter_store_extension.zip
.
└── parameter_store_extension.py
```

```
# parameter_store_extension.py
import urllib
import json
import os

from urllib.parse import urlencode

aws_session_token = os.environ.get('AWS_SESSION_TOKEN')
port = '2773'


def get_param(name: str):
    """
    Get SALT form systems manager/parameter store
    """
    params = dict(name=name)
    req = urllib.request.Request(
        f"http://localhost:{port}/systemsmanager/parameters/get/?{urlencode(params)}&withDecryption=true")
    req.add_header('X-Aws-Parameters-Secrets-Token', aws_session_token)
    config = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

    return json.loads(config)
```

However, I cannot use functions inside `parameter_store_extension.py`, as I do with the first layer.

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'parameter_store_extension'
```

Comment: Whats the handler of the lambda function? (under settings)

Comment: what do you mean? there is no handler inside the zip files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mistake, I should move the `parameter_store_extension.py` inside `python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/` before zipping